# Use objectAtIndex with multiple views

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsview

I have NSViews that are all sub views of my main view.  In the subclasses of the subviews I want to be able to access properties of the different subviews and their methods so I get the subview properties like this

```
MoveFilter *controller = [[[[[NSApp delegate] window] contentView] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Where move filter is the name of my subclass.  When I have more than one subview I need to change the objectAtIndex: to the different subviews.  Would I set up the subviews in an array? if so how do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subviews are already in an array. The subviews method that you're calling on your content view returns an array of all its subviews (that's why you can call objectAtIndex on it like you did in the posted code).

Comment: so what do I change my index values to to access the other subviews? When I put any number greater than 0 it says its out of bounds

Comment: try logging [[[[NSApp delegate]window]contentView]subviews] and see what you get.  It sounds like you only have one subview.